# What .object means for a GroupBy Object

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I keep seeing

```
for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
```

in Tensorflow tutorials. I get what it's doing, and that group is a GroupBy object, but I wonder what the ".object" is there for. I googled "group.object.iterrows", all I  got was Tensorflow object detection code. I tried other variants, but nothing had a GroupBy.object example or description of what it is.

EDIT: here's a tutorial:
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py

See line 70.

Here's another, there are a bunch, actually:

https://www.skcript.com/svr/realtime-object-and-face-detection-in-android-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/

Some more context:
They involve making a tensorflow.train.Example, loading features into it. These were originally taken from some xml from some producing labeling tools, then converted to a csv, then converted to a pandas data frame.

In fact, the code mostly looks like cut-and-paste from some original script with small edits.

Comment: Can you link to a tutorial that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a DataFrame, a Pandas GroupBy object supports accessing columns by attribute access notation, as long as the column name doesn't conflict with "regular" attributes. `object` is merely one of the column names in the grouped data, and `group.object` accesses that column.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

`object` is a column in the `group` DataFrame.